# On the fly image resizing, what "staging" format to choose?

Tags: image-processing

I'm about to build a system which does on-the-fly image resizing. Now the "source" (original) images we have are all in different formats. For example: jpeg, bmp, tiff, various color schemes, etc. A lot!

Now the renderer will be on-the-fly and we are considering a "staging" format. So ALL original assets will be converted into a "staging" format which then will be used during the real image resizing/scaling for the front-end (we plan to do that using a cloud funnction).

Basically my question is; what is the best image format for resizing? Is there something like that?

Comment: If you are happy to lose transparency and colour accuracy, choose JPEG. If you'd like not to be able to store floating point images nor 32-bit images and to be quite slow, choose PNG. If you want something poorly documented, antiquated and that can't retain metadata, BMP is the way to go...

Comment: Yeah? BMP looks "old" to me. Why is it the best format, can you elaborate a bit more? I once heard about a format which contains different sizes of the original image, from small to big. Depending on the requested size, the resizer could -very efficient- pick the best original. Unfortunately I forgot what format this is :(.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your choices are restricted to a lossless format which has the biggest set of the features you need, like transparant and such . I also assume it depends on your transcoding library. My advice is to pick a few and run a few test to make that decision based on your own data and hardware.

AAMOF [JPEG2000](https://jpeg.org/jpeg2000/) was designed to have different layers for transcoding. It also seems a bit quiet there.